# Shape fill won't change and won't show in layers After Effects

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

I'm having an issue where my shape fill won't change, nor will it appear in my timeline>?

Not too sure what's going on?

Any help would be amazing :)

Thanks!
Kristian

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you switch off the (little) Shy icon in the timeline, and search for your layer in the full list of layers, if the shape FILL still didn't appear in the contents of the the shape layer, then you'll have to add it, same way you add a text animator.
Last thing to check is the expression, click 'e' twice when the layer selected, and check your expressions, you may have added an expression on the fill attribute by the expression pick-whip.

Hope that answers the question
AM

Answer (score 0):

"The reason why you don't see it -> it turned on the Shy icon to hide other layers. You can turn it off (check out the attached screenshot).

You have a similar animation I use from [AEJuice Starter Pack](https://aejuice.com/free-plugins/?utm_source=outreach&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=shape_elements&utm_term=ruslan&platform=graphicdesign_stackexchange%22) :)